# Attaching onmouseover after page is rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-6

**Hi,**

When the page first is rendered my div elements looks like this :

```
<div onmousedown="this.className='showhideExtra_down_click';"
   onmouseout="this.className='showhideExtra_down';"
   onmouseover="this.className='showhideExtra_down_hover';"
   class="showhideExtra_down" id="extraFilterDropDownButton">&nbsp;</div>
```

Then i manually updates the onmouse attributes with javascript so it looks like this :

```
<div onmousedown="this.className='showhideExtra_down_click';"
   onmouseout="this.className='showhideExtra_down';"
   onmouseover="this.className='showhideExtra_down_hover';"
   class="showhideExtra_down" id="extraFilterDropDownButton">&nbsp;</div>
```

They looks the same, the big difference is that the first one will change class when hovering and the second will not? Is it not possible to set this after page is rendered?

Please note : I need **IE6 compability**, thats why I use onmouse instead of CSS hover

**BestRegards**

Edit : This is what I found and that works grate, I haven´t tested it in IE6 just yet :

```
$("#extraFilterButton").hover(function() {
                $(this).attr('class','showhideExtra_down_hover');
            }, 
            function() {
                $(this).attr('class','showhideExtra_down');
            });
```

Comment: Why are you using inline JS? jQuery (as your question is tagged) could certainly handle the `hover()` function. As well as remove the click-handlers from the element tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:

```
$('#selector').live('mouseover',function(){//something todo when mouse over})
```

live() allows for dynamic changes

(you can do the same for 'mouseout')

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @maniator's correct answer, I would use:

```
$("#some_id").live("hover",
  function() {
    // do on mouseover
  },
  function() {
    // do on mouseout
  });
```

Comment: @Harsh I think so, jquery has got good ie 6 support but it's been a while since I tried it.

Comment: This look grate, but I can´t get the second function to run on mouseout?

Comment: @SnowJim That can be because the `hover` or `mouseover mouseout` event combination is relatively new (jQuery 1.4.1) so what you can do is 1) use 2 functions or 2) upgrade jQuery, see: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I am using jquery-1.4.1. I have hover ever this to work : http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/a-simple-mouseover-hover-effect-with-jquery/ (se my edit in the main post)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with :

```
    $("#extraFilterDropDownButton").hover(function() {
        if($('#divCategoryFilter').css("display") == 'block'){
            $(this).attr('class','showhideExtra_up_hover');
        }
        else{
            $(this).attr('class','showhideExtra_down_hover');
        }
    }, 
    function() {

        if($('#divCategoryFilter').css("display") == 'block'){
            $(this).attr('class','showhideExtra_up');
        }
        else{
            $(this).attr('class','showhideExtra_down');
        }
    });
```

This is however not yet tested in IE6.